# Values Always Null

Tags: c#, class, textbox, instantiation

I am attempting to access the values of text boxes from a different class.  The text boxes exist in winform1.cs and I want to access them in testing.cs

At the top of testing.cs I have instantiated `winform1 wf = new winform1();` which allows me to see the text boxes with intellisense, but if I type

```
Messagebox.Show(wf.txtfname.Text);
Messagebox.Show(wf.txtlname.Text);
```

I get a null reference exception - if I utilize the immediate window and type `wf.txtfname.Text` it returns `""` - the modifiers for the text boxes are set to public.

What do I need to change so that I can capture the value of these text boxes from a different class?

if it makes a difference, the method I am attempting to show the values in is declared as

```
protected override void()
```

This is syntax from designer.cs for the two text boxes

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtfname;
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtlname;
```

Comment: That windows is already open when you did `winform1 wf = new winform1();` ?

Comment: Yes - the winform is already open when I do the above syntax.

Comment: What textbox declerations do you need to see?  I have a _Leave() event for them, but that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are accessing other instance of the form, not the visible one. Note that if you do

```
winform1 wf = new winform1();
wf.Show();
```

It will show the actual form that you are getting those values.

You need to get the correct object instance to use that. Maybe, if you do not plan to open another instance of that window, you can create a static property that holds the reference.

1. Put that inside the `winform1` class:

   ```
   public static winform1 MainInstance { get; set; }
   ```
2. Put that inside the constructor of the `winform1` class

   ```
   MainInstance = this;
   ```
3. Now, access like that:

   ```
   Messagebox.Show(winform1.MainInstance.txtfname.Text);
   Messagebox.Show(winform1.MainInstance.txtlname.Text);
   ```

Comment: Should the MainInstance = this; go above or below the InitializeComponents();?

Comment: I do not think that should make any difference, but put bellow.

Comment: still is returning ""

Comment: You do not need to call `winform1 wf = new winform1();`. Are you acessing like that? `winform1.MainInstance.txtfname.Text`

Comment: Yes - I was.  I cleaned the solution, saved, closed, reopened, build and now in Immediate window it is showing as desired.